# How to read last block of Stream.Read

Tags: c#

I wrote an extension method as following

```cs
public static void ReadBlock(this Stream stream, Action<string> action, int bufferSize = 8192)
{
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    while (true)
    {
        var count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        if (count == 0) break;
        var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
        action(text);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is the last block which is often less than the size of the buffer is not read.
and the code returns the n-1 block again (the last buffer).

Can anyone help me to read a stream block by block in the correct way based on buffer size?

Comment: You'll want to use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, count)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not telling `Encoding.GetString` how much of the buffer to read.

If you read from the stream and `bufferSize` bytes are available, then it will fill the buffer up with those bytes.

If you read from the stream and less than `bufferSize` bytes are available, it will write those bytes to the beginning of the buffer, but *won't touch the rest of the buffer*. This means the buffer contains `count` bytes of new data, and the rest is full of the data from your last read.

However, `Encoding.GetString` doesn't know this, and will just process the entire buffer. Which might be a mix of old and new data.

The solution, of course, is to tell `Encoding.GetString` how much of the buffer to read:

```
var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, count);
```

---

Note that this approach will *only* work with ASCII, or other encodings which only ever use 1 byte per character. If you move to UTF-8 or UTF-16, etc, then it'll all go horribly wrong. In this case, you'll want to use [a decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getdecoder?view=net-5.0).